# intermittent recording of Kinect inputs using rosbag

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rosbag, frequency

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to record a bag file of Kinect data, which can be run on RGBDSLAM later, as is instructed [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/30249/minimal-topics-for-rgbdslam/). Everything works perfectly, but for my own experiment I would like to record the bag files intermittently, instead of capturing a continuous stream from Kinect.

The purpose is to get data at a very low frequency(say, having a time interval of 10 seconds between 2 inputs), so that I can have a bag file which contains images and depth information from a long time period (20 minutes, for example) while keeping the minimal amount of necessary data. In other words, I would like to get a single frame every 10 seconds or so for the bag file.

I suppose I can do this in a pretty ugly way, which is to run **openni_node.launch** on and off in one terminal, with **rosbag record -O** running in another terminal. But that is actually capturing continuous input in an impulse of time and then stop it, instead of capturing one single frame(as we press "Enter" running the RGBDSLAM with the GUI).

As I am new to ROS, I don't know how to do this, and there seemed no related discussion on this issue. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41444/intermittent-recording-of-kinect-inputs-using-rosbag/) by [testingrosanswer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3012/testingrosanswer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [testingrosanswer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3012/testingrosanswer/) on 2012-08-16**:
Thanks piyushk for the info. Now it is working for online RGBDSLAM, but running offline produces nothing in the screen, even though I have modified the topic config in rgbdslam.launch. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use this node: http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/throttle

It takes in an arbitrary message topic and republishes the message at a desired rate. You can then record the republished message.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An alternative is to use the GUI from [dynamic_reconfigure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure) to set the `data_skip` parameter of [openni_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera). It will only let you reduce the framerate to 3 Hz (and not 0.1 Hz, as you propose), but at 0.1 Hz you won't get any sensible output out of RGBDSLAM anyway (except if the robot is not moving at all in those 10 seconds).

The advantage of this over the `topic_tools` solution is that you turn down the publishing frequency at the source, so you save a little computation time. The downside is that *all* subscribers get the point clouds at low frequency.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1